# Make dropdown close when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make the dropdown close when clicking anywhere in a document, currently it only closes when I click on the dropdown menu itself. Here's what I currently have of the HTML and JQuery:

HTML:

```
<div class="user-menu">
            <div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu">
                  <img src="#" class="user-menu-pic" alt="">
                <span>Name Lastname</span>
                <img src="images/dropdown-icon.png" class="right dropdown-icon" width="30" height="30" alt="">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Change profile picture/background</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Change password</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
      $('#dropdown').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: I hope my answer helps you, if still any Queries feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o5une5s8/)

```js
   $('#dropdown').on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
           $(this).removeClass('open');
           $(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast');
       } else {
           $(this).addClass('open');
           $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
       }
   });
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
       var container = $("#dropdown");

       if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
       &&
       container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
       {
           container.children('ul').slideUp('fast');
       }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-menu">
    <div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu">
        <img src="#" class="user-menu-pic" alt=""> <span>Name Lastname</span>

        <img src="images/dropdown-icon.png" class="right dropdown-icon" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">My Profile</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Change profile picture/background</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Change password</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Note :** Actually it doesn't need two clicks, it's working with very first click. But you can see that when you click on Menu(very first time), so it is already open(i.e. Already slideDown) and does not have class `open`. So it executes the `loop` which **returns false** for `hasClass("open")`. Now in that loop we say menu to `slideDown`, which is already in the `slideDown` State.

If you want better explanation do me a favor add `class="ddmenu open"` to your html like this: `<div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu open">` and then try it again.

Comment: You have to click twice though if you press on the document and the dropdown again :P, but thanks for the help mate :)

Comment: @poseidon23 Check out the fiddle for better results.